# How to solve ElementNotVisible error

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have over 100 row DIVs and I want to click on each rows.

Since some of the higher number rows are not visible on my screen and I am getting the `ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated.`

I have already set my screen on the maximum size. Does anyone knows how will I be able to do this and click on even the rows that are below the bottom of my screen?

```
<div  ng-repeat="row in grid">
    <div id="row{{$index}}">{{title}}</div>
</div>

function clickRow(modifier) {
    describe('Click row ' + modifier, function () {
        it('Click row', function () {
            element(by.id(row + modifier)).click();
        });
    });
}

var a;
var row = 'row';
for(a = 0; a < 100; a++) { clickRow(a); }
```

Comment: Call the `click` event handler directly.

Comment: I have. And its giving me the error above.

Comment: I've understood, that you've programmatically clicked the row, like so: `row.click();`. If this is not the case, please elaborate your question.

Comment: post a fiddle/codepen, it will be very helpful =)

Comment: Are you trying to get a value out of the element before clicking on it? In my experience using sendKeys() and click() work when the element is not currently visible in the viewport

Comment: I agree with @AndresD. Also since Protractor >= 1.3.0 you should be able to to this at once (without a loop): `$$('div[ng-repeat="row in grid"] > div').click();` (feel free to improve that selecter)

Answer (score 0):

Try calling [element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollIntoView) in the browser's js context. You should be able to do that with [browser.executeScript](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md#webdriverwebdriverprototypeexecutescript)